# Prevent access to API in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, express

I have a simple express server written that routes the url /api/employees to a function like so:

```
app.get('/api/employees', mainServerController.list);
```

My callback is just a simple db.find() query, not really that impressive. However, I don't want anyone to be able to type in localhost/api/employees and get a full listing of employees. That is currently what happens.

I've googled around and read some things about making sure a user is authenticated first, but I don't have a login system set up.

How can I restrict access to my /api/employees route to only calls made by the website itself? Or any other solution I might not know about.

Comment: A very naive (and easily circumvented) approach would be to verify that the request was sent via XHR, and not a direct request with `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, but I'm going to tell you right away, this will only stop the most disinterested of attackers. Anyone with 10 minutes and curl would be able to circumvent that. A login/proper token system would be the only decent protection I can think of.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to learn how this stuff works and often times I don't know what to google for. I'll read more about token/auth systems.

Comment: It's definitely a journey. It's important to build a strong foundation early on, since you need to remember not every user's going to use the system how you want. Never trust the client. They lie, cheat, steal, and are in general easy to manipulate. You might want to look into [`passport`](https://npmjs.com/package/passport), which provides a great session management/login middleware. This article might help. https://www.matthewtyler.io/handling-oauth2-with-node-js-and-angular-js-passport-to-the-rescue/